# Difference between two datetime strings: setting timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

//Difference between 2 dates
This function works well but display wrong time format. Pls how can I change the time of this function from GMT to GMT+1? Displays 15hrs 22mins instead of 16hrs 22mins.
Thanks

```
function get_date_diff($start, $end="NOW")
{
        $sdate = strtotime($start);
        $edate = strtotime($end);
        $timeshift = "";

        $time = $edate - $sdate;
        if($time>=0 && $time<=59) {
                // Seconds
                $timeshift = $time.' seconds ';

        } elseif($time>=60 && $time<=3599) {
                // Minutes + Seconds
                $pmin = ($edate - $sdate) / 60;
                $premin = explode('.', $pmin);

                $presec = $pmin-$premin[0];
                $sec = $presec*60;

                $timeshift = $premin[0].' min '.round($sec,0).' sec '."<b>ago</b>";

        } elseif($time>=3600 && $time<=86399) {
                // Hours + Minutes
                $phour = ($edate - $sdate) / 3600;
                $prehour = explode('.',$phour);

                $premin = $phour-$prehour[0];
                $min = explode('.',$premin*60);

                $presec = '0.'.$min[1];
                $sec = $presec*60;

                $timeshift = $prehour[0].' hrs '.$min[0].' min '.round($sec,0).' sec '."<b>ago</b>";

        } elseif($time>=86400) {
                // Days + Hours + Minutes
                $pday = ($edate - $sdate) / 86400;
                $preday = explode('.',$pday);

                $phour = $pday-$preday[0];
                $prehour = explode('.',$phour*24); 

                $premin = ($phour*24)-$prehour[0];
                $min = explode('.',$premin*60);

                $presec = '0.'.$min[1];
                $sec = $presec*60;

                $timeshift = $preday[0].' days '.$prehour[0].' hrs '.$min[0].' min '.round($sec,0).' sec '."<b>ago</b>";


        }
        return $timeshift;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the timezone using the [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) function. If that doesn't work, you have PHP <5.1.0 and should set the `TZ` environment variable. Check [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) for the detailed order of preference used to determine the timezone.

You could also skip all that code you wrote and use the [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to get the resulting datetime string in pretty much any format you desire.

Comment: Thanks. I have already figured it out. The timezone in my php.ini was wrong. I was playing with diff timezones. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @Frank Can you mark the answer as accepted if it's good enough for you? Either that, or add your own answer explaining what you did and accept that.